# freeBSD9.0 autoinstall

Tags: freebsd, automated-install

Everybody, Hello! We use Freebsd9.0 for our workstation. Everytime, we start a new machine. We must install freeBSD manually. And what we want just autoinstall it. That is, we insert the installation cd and it start to install. When we go back. it finish install. So is there any tool or script fit our needs?

Comment: Have you done any research at all on your own? We frown upon "shopping"-style questions who does not bring any relevant discussion to the table (like asking for products/premade scripts).

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [bsdinstall(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdinstall&sektion=8) man page?

Have you asked google, and looked at the [FreeBSD forum threads](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=28862) that it [would tell you to look at]?

Since the answer to your question is present in the documentation (and easily google-able) I'm going to assume you did zero research, and suggest that you go and do that now.

Consider this a gentle public-service flogging. :-)